# How to pass a variable to my webpage

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I load a webpage from my assets in a webview.
Now i need to call a function to init something in the webpage.

I've tryed it with a html GET param:
it works on android 2.3.3 but NOT on all higher versions (webpage unavailable)

Now i a different way to solve my problem by calling a javascript function.
but the following code:

```
<script type="javascript">
var isChecked = "";
function initLoc(name) {
                            isChecked = name;
                            if(isChecked == null)
                                isChecked = "";
                            else
                                document.getElementById(isChecked).style.backgroundImage = "url(../location-button-active.png)";
                    }
```

```
   frontWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/location-front/front.html");  
   frontWebView.loadUrl("javascript:initLoc('"+ locationID +"')");
```

Gives me the following error:

```
 06-19 11:40:07.749: E/Web Console(16210): Uncaught ReferenceError: initLoc is not defined at null:1
```

Does anyone knows what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The page wasn't loaded so to the function wasn't defined yet. 
I call the method now in the onPageFinished and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling a function named `initPainLoc` but the function you have defined is named `initLoc`.

[Take a look at this example](http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html)

Answer (score 0):

The method is `initLoc` and not `initPainLoc`.

You must call:

`frontWebView.loadUrl("javascript:initLoc('"+ locationID +"')");`